# How to calculate expected cost of successive events?

Tags: probability

Suppose playing fee of the game is $\$100$. To win the prize, I need to win $3$ times continuously. And the winning chance is $70\%$. So how to calculate the expected cost of the prize?

I came up $2$ approaches.

First:

Calculating the 3 wins probability $(70\%)^3$ then divided by $(\$100*3)$

```
$300 / 34.3% = $875
```

Second:

Recalculate the expected cost each game

```
$100 / 70% = $143

($143 + $100) / 70% = $347

($347 + $100) / 70% = $638
```

I don't know which one is correct or both wrong. Could someone explain it to me?

EDIT: I need the prize no matter how much I spent, I will continue to play until I get the prize.

Comment: Could you clarify the game? Do you play exactly three times, or you continue until you won three times continuously?
What do you mean exactly by expected cost of the price? (in the case where it is not sure if you get the price or not)

Comment: In that case that you just play on until you win it's much more complicated. You need to consider the different ways to spend a certain amount of money; it's a bit tricky. In the end you will surely end up with some geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

A rigorous and elementary approach is to consider, not only $c_0$ the expected cost of the game at the start, which you want to compute, but also $c_1$ the remaining expected cost of the game after exactly one win, and $c_2$ the remaining expected cost of the game after exactly two wins.

Calling $p=70\%$ the winning chance and $f=\$100$ the fee, and conditioning by the result of the next game, one gets $$c_0=f+p\cdot c_1+(1-p)\cdot c_0$$ but also $$c_1=f+p\cdot c_2+(1-p)\cdot c_0$$ and $$c_2=f+p\cdot0+(1-p)\cdot c_0$$
Solving this $3\times3$ affine system with unknowns $(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ yields $$c_0=\left(1+\frac1p+\frac1{p^2}\right)\cdot f$$ that is, numerically, $$c_0\approx\$447$$